# How should I take care of a lemon plant in a container?

Tags: containers, lemons

I have a lemon plant in my balcony in a container. I don't know how it grew there, but I am sure that it is a lemon plant. I haven't noticed its growth until now. I actually know nothing about lemon plants, but I want that plant to grow and bear fruit. What care must I take? It's about 20 cm (almost 8 inches) tall now. I live in India. The plant gets plenty of sunshine. Its in a pot almost 15cm in radius and 1 foot in height. Is it enough? Also please tell the amount of water it will need. Its a citrus lemon.Any suggestions?

Comment: By lemon plant, do you mean a citrus lemon? Or a lemon geranium or something else? A photograph would be very useful if you can attach one please, and what part of the world are you in?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, we still need more information, especially a picture of your plant, to know exactly what you need. Do you have any idea how old it is? If you look through our other questions about [lemon plants](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lemons), you might find something that will help you. Thanks!

Comment: How can i attach a photo to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Lemon plants are sensitive to cold. Bring the plant in before a frost. You can treat it like any other houseplant. It likes plenty of sunlight. Put it back outside when the weather permits. If you leave it inside all year, it starts to suffer a bit. 
Lemon trees can get big. You will eventually need a container 18 - 24 inches in diameter. You might want to find out the load capacity on your balcony. The plant and wet soil can be very heavy.

Comment: Mmm, I don't think they get frosts in India.  Maybe you could add more to this answer?

Comment: It can get cold, depending on how far north. If exposed to a freeze, you can lose the lemon tree, even Meyers lemons (the most cold-hardy). I think the worst thing for lemon trees would be drying heat. Critters start to attack when the trees are stressed, and the leaves drop.

Comment: Please read the question, the original poster lives in India.  Most gardens in India do not get frost.